# Using instance methods with Django Model

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement for methods for eac Model object in my project. get_all() , get_by_id(),add(),remove() and maybe others.
I need to use them by each object . When I declare an object automatically can call one of those methods.
The problem , I don't want to duplicate the code of the four methods in each class . 
Is there a way to write them once, and link them to each object.
I heared about instance methods in python.
How can use this.
Please a help
Thanks
...

Answer (score 3):

You can have a base manager which has all these methods and inherit them. [Django model and manager inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def get_all():
        return <something>

class A(MyModel):
    pass

class B(MyModel):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should seperate row-level actions (like delete(), get_some_calculated_attribute()) which go in Model classes from table level actions (like create(), filter()) which go in Manager classes.